# Unable to access GitHub; Couldn't connect to server

Tags: linux-mint, git, github

I've been trying to clone a git repository (several, actually) and I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repository-name': Couldn't connect to server
```

My internet connection is working correctly and I've had no issues with it. I can `ping github.com` with no issues (I believe) as well. I also set up my git global configuration. I tested out other commands that require connecting to github, such as `git pull`/`git push` and I get the same error.

Comment: Is this a private repository? In that case, did you set up your SSH keys correctly on github?

Comment: Are you connecting from a corporate/university network? They could enforce the use of one of their proxies for http/https connections. Can you use `wget`/`curl` on sites such as google.com?

Comment: What does `openssl s_client -connect github.com:443` say?

Comment: @xenoid I've tried both from my home (off campus) as well as university network. wget and curl are both working on google.com.

Comment: @AndrásKorn That returns the following error:
"140395971405504:error:0200200D:system library:connect:Permission denied:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:108:
140395971405504:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:109:
connect:errno=13"

Comment: @AndreiSavin Nope, all the repos I've tried (Vundle, my own repos) have been public. I haven't tried setting up my ssh keys yet though

Comment: It sounds like a local firewall rule is preventing you from making TCP connections to github.com:443. That's probably why the `connect()` syscall returns EPERM.

Comment: Sorry, I meant EACCES (errno==13). EPERM would be 1.

Comment: I am having the same issue in a raspberry pi that I had setup previously. I can git add and git commit, but when trying to git push I get the same error as you. Did you find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 2):

Since your `connect()` syscall returns `EACCES` (errno==13), based on `connect(2)` there are two possibilities:

- "The user tried to connect to a broadcast address without having the socket broadcast flag enabled"; or
- "the connection request failed because of a local firewall rule".

The first one would require weird and unlikely entries in `/etc/hosts` or an even weirder DNS setup, so my money is on the second (local firewall rule).

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/repository-name': Couldn't connect to server
```

### just create a token key to access your repository

- Got to https://github.com/settings/tokens
- Generate Personal access tokens
- Choose a note add permissions (give all)
- And, also choose the expiration date

Now after doing this copy it and use it as your password in the terminal as

```
Username for 'https://github.com': your_username
Password for 'https://your_username@github.com': personal access tokens
```

#### There you go

Comment: Nice detailed answer, but f you read the question's comments, the Original Poster added some details on additional error messages that might mean your answer might not apply.

Comment: As per the additional issues, I too got those issues in the same pattern but, eventually, GitHub itself showed a way to do so as per the authentication to access i.e. to push or pull kind of things to git was changed by using the token key to do instead of the followed way we usually do, you can find it here https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/. Through this only I was able to perform the required operations. Thank you very much for your comment.